# the web freezes during a long loop

Tags: node.js, nonblocking

Lets say I have a very long loop that takes few minutes to complete.

```
for(let i=0; i<10000; i++){
  db.query(`INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES('data')`, function(error, result){
});
```

From what I understand, even if the loop is not complete, users can interact with the web because of non-blocking I/O.
But until the loop finishes, the web is frozen.

Anything I am doing wrong? Or any suggestion would be nice.

Comment: No - the main thread will be busy until the task finishes, which will necessarily be after the loop finishes (unless you have `await` in there). The ten thousand jobs of inserting stuff into the database can wait and be done later (the non-blocking IO you are mentioning); but the loop itself is non-negotiable.

Comment: If I use **await** inside the loop, the main thread will respond to other tasks first? Do you have a link where it deals with a similar example?

Comment: I'm not specifically suggesting `await` inside the loop, just saying it would be a counterexample where the loop wouldn't need to finish before the thread is freed. You can get a similar effect with plain promises as well, though the function would have to be rewritten much more drastically (you can't then have a 10000-loop).

Comment: another question. the loop above its asynchronous right?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. All loops are synchronous unless you have `await` in them.

Comment: oh seriously.. I did not know that.. I thought that loop was asynchronous. No wonder it took so long to complete. Ill have a look at `await`. Thanks!

Comment: Awaiting anything is normally undesirable if you can avoid it. The whole benefit of it is that stuff can go on in the background while the rest of your code runs as it's all running on different threads - if you await, you are forcing your code to wait for whatever it is to finish. If you are doing this 10000 times, it will still take ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function breathe() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve));
};

async function non_synchronous_loop_using_await() {
  for(let i=0; i<10000; i++){
    db.query(`INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES('data')`, function(error, result){
      // ...
    });
    if (!(i % 1000)) await breathe(); // every 1000 iterations let other tasks run
  }
}
```